# Convert Oracle enterprise to redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, oracle, rhn

Has someone converted successfully a running Oracle Enterprise Linux server to redhat enterprise and was able to register it on RHN network? Tried to install kernel from redhat, updated the rhnsd binaries. I have the following errors every time I try to register on Redhat;

```
This system is not subscribed to any channels.

RHN channel support will be disabled.

Stopping Red Hat Network Daemon:                           [  OK  ]

Starting Red Hat Network Daemon:                           [  OK  ]

rhnsd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd do this. I'd almost expect a move to CentOS, but going from one commercial to another... Why?

Answer (score 7):

There is only one supported way that I am aware of to do what you're asking:
**Reinstall**. **The**. **Machine**.

If you would like to investigate other alternatives I suggest contacting RedHat support.
There is no sense in paying for the Enterprise licensing if you are going to have the machine in a state that RedHat won't be able to support.